# Check if "MAN_ABC_COMMENT_CHANGE" doesn't occurs in Column D

Tags: vba, excel

In Column A, it has ID and it is random.

Sometimes ID repeat 2 times, sometimes 10 times, it is different all the time.

I need to check if "MAN_ABC_COMMENT_CHANGE" doesn't occur.

If for example in image below for ID = 12345 in column D "MAN_ABC_COMMENT_CHANGE" never occurred, so in new sheet or somehow show that for id 12345 MAN_ABC_COMMENT_CHANGE never occurred.

I have over 5000 rows of data and over 1000 ID

[image: a pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method...

1) set up a Pivot table of ID from the data

2) add a formula in B2 =countifs(Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!D:D,"MAN_ABC_COMMENT_CHANGE")

3) copy down (double click the bottom right of cell to autofill)

4) the rows with zero are the ones you want (can filter them as required)

Comment: I am sure you could do all of this in pivot table, but this is easy to understand.

Comment: I am sorry I never used Pivot, I created Pivot Table like you said, and checked ID so it put ID in column A, but don't know what to do after that.

Comment: I think I got it, I wasn't able to put in B2 but I was able to put that formula in H, in sheet where Pivot table is created.

Comment: How can show in Pivot table, all the C_ID if there are any, if not show it blank.

Comment: if you create pivot based upon whole sheet, then can add any of the columns by adding fields. If you loo up pivot tables on Here and Utube, there are many good tutorials etc.